# PHP code to edit different lines of a text file

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv

I have a text file in the following format, let's call it stats.txt:

```
valueA1, valueA2, valueA3, valueA4
valueB1, valueB2, valueB3, valueB4
valueC1, valueC2, valueC3, valueC4
valueD1, valueD2, valueD3, valueD4
```

I want four text boxes or textareas to populate with this code in an html document and when form is submitted, append to the corresponding lines of the text file. I'm not very knowledgeable with php so can't figure out a way to do this.

My current html file looks like this:

```
$url = 'editor.php';
$file = 'stats.txt';

// check if form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['text1']))
{
    // save the text contents
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text1']);

    // redirect to form again
    header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
    printf('<a href="%s">Updated</a>.', htmlspecialchars($url));
    exit();
}

// read the textfile
$text = file_get_contents($file);

?>
```

I couldn't figure out how to loop between the lines of the text file, so have this chunk of horrible code to get the value of each line:

```
    <?php
    //for Line 1
    $myLine1 = 1 ; 
    $linefile1 = new SplFileObject($file);
    $linefile1->seek($myLine1-1);

    //for Line 2
    $myLine2 = 2 ; 
    $linefile2 = new SplFileObject($file);
    $linefile2->seek($myLine2-1);

    //for Line 3
    $myLine3 = 3 ; 
    $linefile3 = new SplFileObject($file);
    $linefile3->seek($myLine3-1);

    //for Line 4
    $myLine4 = 4 ; 
    $linefile4 = new SplFileObject($file);
    $linefile4->seek($myLine4-1);
    ?>
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
#stuff 1
<textarea id="stuff" name="stuff[]"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($linefile1) ?></textarea>
#stuff 2
<textarea id="stuff" name="stuff[]"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($linefile2) ?></textarea>
#stuff 3
<textarea id="stuff" name="stuff[]"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($linefile3) ?></textarea>
#stuff 4
<textarea id="stuff" name="stuff[]"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($linefile4) ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
<input type="reset" />
</form>
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: You should use explode() to put each value into an array, since separated by commas. If you have control over how it is stored, you'd be better off to use serailize so it will be already stored as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the lines and display textareas.  Using file() to put the file into array

```
 <?php $file = file('stats.txt');?>

  <form action="" method="post">
     <?php
     foreach($file as $line) {
        echo "<textarea id='stuff' name='stuff[]'>".htmlspecialchars($line)."</textarea>";
     };?>
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="reset" />
</form>
```

Then when you submit the form

```
    if(isset($_POST['stuff'])){
        $text = join("\n", $_POST['stuff']);
        file_put_contents($file, $text);
    };
```

Comment: `foreach($_POST['stuff'] as $val){
           $text.=$val."\n";
        }` can be replaced with `$text = join("\n", $_POST['stuff']);` but, at first, it should be check that it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I wrote to store and retrieve data from a text file, that you can use as an example:

```
// Save Check Boxes in Serial Form for later retrieval
$myFile = "equipment.txt";
if($save == "yes"){
$stringData = serialize(array($container_20,$container_40,$container_45,$container_RF,$container_HQ,$container_Chassis));
file_put_contents($myFile, $stringData);
}

// Read Saved File and Populate Check Boxes
$recoveredData = file_get_contents($myFile);
list($container_20,$container_40,$container_45,$container_RF,$container_HQ,$container_Chassis) = unserialize($recoveredData);
```